# Слитно/раздельно? Одна или две н?

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные, причастия, нн

Верно ли написание?
**Почти что не ношеное платье**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не верно.

"Почти" указывает на качество (слитное написание, нет отрицания). Платье почти какое? Неношеное. Вопрос "платье почти не какое?" не подходит.

Н одна:
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/неношеный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)
Вот там по ссылке как раз хороший пример, про платье:
*Тали надела на себя крепдешиновое **платье (почти неношеное)**, красную шерстяную кофту и красные туфли, привезённые из города.* Ф. А. Искандер, «Сандро из Чегема», (Книга 1), 1989 г.